# How to tell grunt to look for modules in the local node_modules?

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, npm

I try to run the `compass` task:

```
» grunt compass:dist
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
rbenv: compass: command not found

The `compass' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  1.9.3-p448

Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

It is referring to this:

```
» rbenv versions
  system
  1.9.3-p448
* 2.1.0 (set by ..../app/.ruby-version)
```

But who cares about the ruby installation? The `compass` module is installed, **locally in my `app/node_modules`**:

```
» npm list | head
app-settings@0.0.0 .../app
├── compass@0.1.0
├── ember-template-compiler@1.6.1
├─┬ grunt@0.4.2
│ ├── async@0.1.22
│ ├── coffee-script@1.3.3
```

I have several questions:

1. When are the modules going to be taken from the ruby installation, and when from the local  `node_modules`?
2. How can I solve my problem, and tell grunt that the compass module is indeed installed, in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 4):

It was confusing the global `ruby` and `gems` with the local ones. The right way to go about this is:

```
rbenv local 2.1.0   # DO THIS FIRST: select the ruby version to use
gem install compass # install the gems with the selected ruby version
rbenv rehash        # recompute all shims for ruby / gems
```

And now you can verify:

```
rbenv versions
ruby --version
compass --version
which ruby
which compass
```